# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'mod'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)

x = float(input("Первое число: "))
y = input("Операция: ")
z = float(input("Второе число: "))

if y == '*':
    print(x * z)
elif y == '+':
    print(x + z)
elif y == '-':
    print(x - z)
elif y == 'pow':
    print(x**z)
if (y=='mod' or y=='div' or y=='/') and z == 0:
    print('Деление на 0!')
#Основной код    
elif y==('mod'):
    print(x % z)

elif y==('div'):
    print(x//z)

elif y==('/'):
    print(x/z)
```

> Failed test #1. Runtime error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "jailed_code", line 4, in 
>       z = float(input("второе число "))
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'mod'

Comment: На Stackoverflow не принято выкладывать код скриншотом.В следующий раз пожалуйста прочитайте [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вероятно в 14 строке должно быть не `... and y == 0`, а `... and z == 0`

Comment: Спасибо! Исправил, но проблема осталась. При делении по модулю на ноль (x % z), необходимо получить результат "Деление на 0!", а в редакторе кода ничего выдает...

Comment: @Andrew_Mozdok приведите ваш исправленный код текстом (а не скриншотом) и те данные, на которых у вас происходит проблема.

Comment: Вам уже пару раз сказали - приведите код текстом, а не скриншотом. иначе вопрос будет закрыт

Answer (score 0):

14 строчка, в конце должна быть проверка `z == 0`, вместо `y == 0`

Comment: Спасибо! Исправил, но проблема осталась. При делении по модулю на ноль (x % z), необходимо получить результат "Деление на 0!", а в редакторе кода ничего выдает...